# Can someone recommend a free simple photo editor with a tool that blends a specific details I don't want to be seen?

Tags: photo-editing

All I want to know is some free photo editor with which I could camouflage some details in photo like making it blend with all the colours the particular details is made of. I know that some time ago I was doing it with some basic photo editor, but now cannot remember which one. Also online editors will do.

Comment: Hard to know what exactly you need, but [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) is free and if you add the [G'Mic plug-in](https://gmic.eu/gimp.shtml) (all free) there are some powerful tools for things like [inpainting](https://patdavid.net/2014/02/getting-around-in-gimp-gmic-inpainting.html).

Comment: Specific product recommendations are off topic here. You may have better success at [Software recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to re-focus (recover) an intentionally blurred image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35097/15871) and [How would I blur something out of a photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/57022/15871)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for but sounds like you want to retouch something out of an image? If so almost any photo image editor now has some sort of basic "clone stamping" features. Or you could manually paint it out by hand with standard brushes. GIMP would work in either case...

Or are you trying to make it disappear like a "predator type" illusion where its not camouflaged but blending in... If that's what you want you would need to give more details because there are several approaches both 2D and 3D and depends on level of detail and lots of other things.